# Collection of short stories about fictional, I think, alien experiences

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I can't remember the name of it, but there's a book that is a collection of fictional, I believe, short stories about aliens. I think it focused on youth experiences. I remember two of the stories in particular:

- In one story, the alien came to the kids in their home, and made them laugh until they weren't able to stop and it got harder to breathe. I think it took place on a ranch, or something?
- In the other story, it involved a teenager making a delivery. He was on the road, and got this urge to make this exit, and I think he followed his urge and took the exit. He came upon some object, I think? Anyway, he made the delivery but when he went back to his boss, his boss was like, "How'd you deliver it so fast? Don't rush things!" He had lost his concept of time after having that experience.

Please help, I'd love to re-read this book.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site, including tips on story identification questions.